# polymer with spring mvc binding

Tags: spring, polymer

I would like to use polymer components in spring mvc project. 
But, I am finding it difficult to bind Spring MVC models to polymer components. 
Is it possible to bind spring mvc models to polymer components ?

Thanks.

Comment: They work on different platforms. Spring is server-side, polymer is on browser. Spring and polymer won't care about the other, so it depends. Are you using them properly. Please show what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

I'm working with Grails (based on Spring mvc) an polymer passing JSON from controller to views. [Here you can see en example of one view](https://github.com/votingsystem/votingsystem/blob/master/Vickets/grails-app/views/app/user.gsp)

Within the controller:

```
render(view:'user', model:[dataMap:(resultMap as JSON)])
```